# How to await button's listeners to resolve in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I am doing frontend tests in **Jest** using `jsdom` environment which lets me simulate **DOM** tree and manually invoke things like `button.click()`.

What I'd like to achieve is to `await button.click()` which as I imagine should await for all button's listeners to resolve their promises but unfortunately it doesn't work like that.

Let's take this code as an example:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        const button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', async () => this.fetch());
    }

    async fetch(): Promise<void> {
        await this.sleep();
    }

    sleep() {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
    }
}
```

Now imagine I have some async **Jest** test and I am manually invoking `button.click()` expecting it to wait 2000ms:

```
async fun(): Promise<void> {
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    
    await button.click(); //I expect this await to sleep for 2000ms but it resolves instantly
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the environment isn't waiting for your event listeners to complete. It's fire and forget.

Instead, let's take a step back. What is the test about? Do you want to test a certain change in the frontend? For example: If there is some kind of loading indicator, you could test for the presence of the loading indicator in the DOM, instead of testing the inner workings of the class / code.

An example of this with jest, reactjs and @testing-library/react could look like this.

```
// render the DOM
const { getByRole, getByText } = render(
    <App />
)

const button = getByRole("button", { name: "Submit" })

// click the button
button.click()

// wait till the text appears within the DOM
await waitFor(() => {
    getByText("Successfully submitted!")
})
```

Where **waitFor** is the key function here. It checks in intervals if the supplied callback succeeds. Only if the **waitFor** completes, the test will continue.

Please not that the example uses reactjs, but in it's core this post is about the idea of waiting for a signal in the DOM, not about a certain library.

But I might be on the wrong track here, feel free to supply more informations if so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is you will have to add await here:

```
  constructor() {
        const button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', async () => await this.fetch());
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this fails as well. VSCode tells me that this await is redundant and I can remove it.